# Why doesn't this converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

Why doesn't $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x}~\mathrm{d}x$$ converge? I mean you would think that because of symmetry the area from the negative side and positive side cancel out, resulting in the integral equaling zero.

By the way, I'm familiar with the way to test if an integral converges by splitting the integral into $0$ to $1$ and $0$ to $-1$ and adding up the integral sums. I don't really understand why this is valid though in the case of symmetry.

Comment: I had the same question in my Real Analysis course and it has to do with the definition of the Riemann Integral. There are (if memory serves me correctly) other integral definitions that allow for such an integral to "cancel-out" due to symmetries.

Comment: See [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: You don't integrate with symmetry in mind.

Comment: @user157227 <<puts on physicist cap>> On the contrary! Symmetry is best way to integrate. <<puts mathecist cap back on>> Then again, we should probably prove that.

Comment: @DavidH It's different because everything is absolutely convergent in physics.

Comment: First provide definition of "converge" that you will use.  Then check whether this satisfies it.  As pointed out below, with the definition from elementary calculus, this does not converge.  Perhaps you can define "asd-convergence" and show that this does converge.  Then we need to know if there are any useful properties of asd-convergence.

Comment: Also look up "Improper integral".

Comment: Note it's the same idea as results like 1+2+3+4+... = -12 or whatever. Your intuition is sensible, but it's based on false leaps in logic for what makes rigorous sense.

Comment: @djechlin: right, to be rigorous it's $-1/12$. To get $-12$ requires spurious manipulation of non-converging series ;-)

Comment: @user157227 That's not true.

Comment: @Felix Only joking :)

Comment: @user157227 Fine. Thanks you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The integral as you've written isn't well-defined - what you've written is:

$\qquad$Integrate $\frac1x$ along the line running from $-1$ to $+1$

However, since $\frac1x$ **isn't defined at 0**, this doesn't make sense.

As such, the integral as you've written it is slightly ambiguous. The answer to whether or not the integral converges will depend on how you define it. There are two ways of doing this:

---

In general, when seeing an integral like this, we are referring to:

$1$)

$$\lim_{\epsilon, \delta \to 0}\left(\int_{-1}^{-\delta}\frac1x\mathrm dx+\int_\epsilon^1\frac1x\mathrm dx\right)\\=\left(\lim_{\delta \to 0}\int_{-1}^{-\delta}\frac1x\mathrm dx\right)+\left(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_\epsilon^1\frac1x\mathrm dx\right)$$

In this case, because we are allowing $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to converge to $0$ at different rates, the integral will not generally converge.

The only way to make this integral to converge will be to impose a relation on $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ such as $\epsilon = \delta$. However, when writing the above integral, we usually mean that we are considering the convergence of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ without these restrictions, and hence this integral will diverge.

---

However, we could also consider:

$2$)

$$\lim_{\delta \to 0}\left(\int_{-1}^{-\delta}\frac1x\mathrm dx+\int_\delta^1\frac1x\mathrm dx\right)$$
Here, the two integrals are converging at the same rate, and in this case, the integral is $0$.

I'm guessing this is what you intuitively had in mind when you said that the positive and negative sides should cancel each other out. However, this integral is **not the same as (1)**, and when writing $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1\frac1x\mathrm dx$, a writer will normally be referring to ($1$) and not ($2$).

---

Contrast this to the integral $$\int_2^4\frac1x$$

As in ($1$), we can write this integral as

$$\lim_{\epsilon, \delta \to 0}\left(\int_{2}^{3-\delta}\frac1x+\int_{3+\epsilon}^4\frac1x\right)$$

However, in this case, **both integrals converge separately** and hence the total integral will converge. This is different to ($1$) where both integrals diverge separately, and hence their sum will diverge.

Comment: I don't understand why $\frac{1}{x}$ not being defined at $0$ would affect integrability. I mean using Riemann sums you can split the function into any number of finite rectangles and the sum of the area of the rectangles would be defined. So why wouldn't this extend to infinite rectangles?

Comment: The point is that you will have rectangles on the negative side that will be of different widths to the ones on the positive side. The only way for the integral to be zero would be to impose the condition that the rectangles have the same width - but this is not a natural assumption to make.

Comment: @asd There are two issues at play here. You are not allowed to re-arrange your infinite sum because it is not absolutly convergent. By the [Riemann Series Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) you would be able to make your integral equal to whatever you would like.

Comment: A function being undefined on a set of measure zero doesn't seem to be much of a barrier to integrating.  As an example, integrate $1/(sgn(x) * |x^{(1/2)}|)$ from -1 to 1 -- it is undefined at 0 as well.

Comment: @Yakk I haven't said that it makes a difference. Just that $\int_{-1}^1\frac1x$ is essentially an abuse of notation that needs to be explained. Also - for the record, if there is an essential singularity at a single point, it makes a huge difference when trying to integrate.... so a function not being defined on a measure $0$ set can and does make a difference. The point here is that there is a pole at $0$, and that the integral is unbounded near $0$, not that the function is undefined at $0$

Comment: @Mathmo123 Not all techniques are bothered by that: the difficulty for a particular technique to be used shouldn't be treated like a fundamental problem.  It really is not the fundamental problem.  The fundamental problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Why would the rectangles be a different size if the partition is regular? I thought the entire definition of a regular partition was that the width of the rectangles are the same?

Comment: @Yakk not all techniques are bothered by that. However Riemann integration *is* bothered by that

Comment: @asd you *can* define the rectangles to be regular, and if you do then the integral will converge. This is what happens in ($2$). However, the integral as you've written it generally refers to ($1$), where we consider the two integrals as being completely separate. In this case, there is no reason the rectangles should be the same size

Comment: @Mathmo123 Oh I see! So the integral would be defined if Riemann sums were defined using regular partitions instead of general ones. Am I correct?

Comment: @asd no, the crux of the issue is the Riemann Series Theorem which is the reason why you cannot sum the rectangles in whichever order you want.

Comment: Not quite. Riemann sums *are* defined using regular partitions. However in this case, because the function is undefined at $0$, we have to split the integral into two separate integrals, integrate both separately, and then add them back together. But these two separate integrals are completely independent. So whilst in each integral the widths are the same, the widths in one won't be the same as the widths in the other

Comment: @user157227 But you aren't summing in a random order. Don't Riemann sums always start with the "leftest" rectangle and move to the right? (In other words, start at the lower bound of the interval and move towards the right)

Comment: @asd that's correct. However if you were to do that you would get stuck as you try to cross the $0$ line and you'd find that your integral was infinite. To use symmetry, you would need to sum one from the left and one from the right to cancel each other out.

Comment: There is a difference between finite discontinuities at poles. More significantly though, the integral doesn't converge in an open ball around $0$. None of the rectangles can cross $0$, and that makes a difference. For example, how would you fit $3$ equal sized rectangles in?

Answer (score 5):

The main issue here is that, despite the odd-ness of the integrand function, $\frac{1}{x}$ is not a Riemann integrable function over $(0,1)$, hence the value of such integral, if existing, would be something like $\infty-\infty$.

Also notice that:
$$\int_{(-1,-a/n)\cup(b/n,1)}\frac{dx}{x}=-\log\frac{n}{a}+\log\frac{n}{b}=\log\frac{a}{b}.$$
By choosing different values for $a$ and $b$ and taking the limit as $n\to +\infty$, you get different hypothetical values for your integral.

Comment: Why is the function not Riemann integrable? I mean visually speaking you can split the function into any number of (finite) rectangles with the sum of the rectangles being defined. So why can't you extend this to infinite rectangles?

Comment: In order that a function is Riemann-integrable over $[-1,1]$, it must be Riemann integrable over any sub-interval of $[-1,1]$. Now, what $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x}$ should be? Since the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\log x$, the value of the integral should be $-\log(0)$, i.e. $+\infty$. This gives that the Riemann sums over $[0,1]$ do not converge, hence $f(x)$ *is not* Riemann-integrable over a superset of a neighbourhood of zero.

Comment: Why must a function be Riemann integrable over any subinterval for it to be integrable over an interval? This seems like an arbitrary condition.

Comment: It just follows from the definition of Riemann integrability. The limit values of the Riemann sums must be finite. If this does not happen on a sub-interval, it cannot happen on the big interval, too.

Comment: Sorry Jack, I don't see how that follows. I looked over the definition of Riemann sums and don't see how it implies that if it doesn't happen on a subinterval it cannot happen on the big one too.

Comment: You are twisting my words. I said the if $f(x)$ is not Riemann integrable on $I$, it cannot be Riemann integrable on $J\supset I$.

Comment: Yeah, but can you explain why?

Comment: Assume that the Riemann sums are unbounded over $I$. How can they be bounded over $J$?

Comment: Because of symmetry. Kinda like how $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} 1$ and $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} -1$ have an infinite value yet adding them $\sum _{n=1}  ^{\infty} (-1)^n$ oscillates between finite values.

Comment: Just to be clear. Assume that the Riemann sums are unbounded over $I$ and that are unbounded "in the opposite direction" over $J\setminus I$. By refining the partition on $I$ only, you get an hypothetical value of the integral that is greater than any positive real number. By refining the partition on $J\setminus I$ only, you get an hypothetical value of the integral that is less than any negative real number. Conclusion: the integral does not exist.

Comment: This is the same as saying that the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(-1)^n$ does not converge.